# Jquery Autocomplete to populate tree based sepearated by a string

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

I have a requirement as follows:

I have to use autocomplete feature which will generate the text in input as follows: projectname.filename
Where projectname is retrieved from one table and filename is retrieved from another dependent table. 
I have a code for autocomplete to one table. But, whenever I add '.' in input box, it should search for 2nd table for filenames for that respective project.

Can someone help me out on how to resolve this?

Here is the code, I used for retrieving data from one table. My requirement is, when I add '.', and start typing, it should populate based on that project name and show only filenames related to that project.

```
$( ".ac-default" ).autocomplete({
      source: "<?php echo base_url('MainController/get_projects_list'); ?>"
  });
```

Comment: is there an error in the dom console?

Comment: @KelvinBarsana There is no error as of now. I don't know how to proceed further like using autocomplete again for the same input based on the item selected in the first level of autocomplete.

Comment: any help would be appreciated.